# Linq query does not populate a property

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

I have a linq query that is running inside a method, which is being called inside a for loop:

```
var allUsers = userRepository.getAll();

foreach (var user in allUsers)
            {
                UserWithExtras userWithExtras = createUserWithExtrasFromLoginName(user.LoginName);
                int userId = userWithExtras.userId;


            }

--------------------------------------------
public static createUserWithExtrasFromLoginName(string loginName){
    var user = (from u in userDb.Users
        where u.Login.ToLower().Equals(login.ToLower())
        select u);
    int a = u.userId;
}
```

I have 15 users in my database, for the first 10 users with IDs from 1 to 10, everything is retrieved properly, after that, the IDs are not populated properly anymore, i.e. in order, the retrieved Users have these IDs:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,10,10,8,0

I have traced the issue in the query in createUserWithExtrasFromLoginName, and the last retrieved object actually has the ID 0, eventhough in the db the ID is 15.

I have checked the dbml file, and made sure Delay Loaded is set to false for this property. Both in dbml file and in the database the userId property is set to be a primary key.

any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: That method doesn't look like it would even compile.  Where would it get "u" when assigning a?

Comment: should '.Equals(login.ToLower())' actually be '.Equals(loginName.ToLower())'?

Comment: You're doing an awful lot of db back-and-forth for what you're trying to acheive (or we're missing some information).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks anyone who tried to answer this, I tried answering my own question yesterday but stackoverflow didn't let me, I basically dropped the Users table from the dbml file and re-inserted it again, and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The method where you're using the LINQ query doesn't specify a return value. From the looks of your code, that method should return a *UserWithExtras* object.

Comment: you are right, I forgot to add that line, but yes, it does return a UserWithExtras.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, it looks like you could replace all of that with a single LINQ query.  More details might be helpful.

```
var userIds = from u in userDb.Users 
               where u.Login.ToLower().Equals(login.ToLower()) 
               select u.userId;
```

This assumes that userRepository and userDb are accessing the same store.  In which case, there seems to be some confusion.  By querying for all users and then iterating over users and querying all users for the userId on the login name you'll be performing WAY more work than needed (see cartesian product).

Comment: I am not trying to get a list of IDs, I am trying to get a list of users, and then for each user pass it to a method that creates a instantiates a subclass of user based on security settings, and returns that instance. the syntax or application logic is not important here as everything compiles and works, I had to remove some lines of code in order to ensure information is not exposed unnecessarily, the issue is that a linq query does not populate the ID of all objects, the first 10 or 11 are populated correctly, and then the rest are not.

Comment: The code you posted isn't even close to what you describe here.  But again, I would advise not getting the full list of users and then iterating over that list to build the list based on security settings.  Just get what you need in the 1st place.